# Toggle option in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny dashboard, I have a radio button as follows,

```
radioButtons("view", "View Type", c("Count", "Percent"), selected = "Count")
```

Now based on this radio button selection I want my output tabs to be toggled based upon the selection. What is mean is that if i select "Count" then the "Count" view should be shown and "Percent" view should be disabled.

Below, is the code for my main tab,

```
mainPanel(width = 9,
   tabsetPanel("tab",
   tabPanel(strong("Count of Objects"), tableOutput("mon")),
   tabPanel(strong("% of Objects"), tableOutput("mon_per")))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the updateTabsetPanel() function. This is the code:

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)


    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(


            headerPanel("Tabsets"),
            sidebarPanel(
                    radioButtons("view", "View Type:",
                                 c("Count", "Percent"), 
                                 selected = "Count")

            ),
            mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(id = "tab",
                                tabPanel(title = "Count of objects", 
                                         value = "countsOfObjects", 
                                         tableOutput("mon")),
                                tabPanel(title = "% of Objects", 
                                         value = "percentOfObjects", 
                                         tableOutput("mon_per")))

                    )
            )
    )
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
            observeEvent(input$view, {
                    if (input$view == "Count") {
                            updateTabsetPanel(session, "tab",
                                              selected = "countsOfObjects"
                            )      
                    } else {
                            updateTabsetPanel(session, "tab",
                                              selected = "percentOfObjects"
                            )                         
                    }

            })

    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. But, the issue which i am facing right now is that as i have separate countofobjects and percentofobjects calculation the view is not working, Means toggle is not working.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more since I didn't grasp your comment completely.

Comment: As of now i have two tabs in main panel - countsOfObjects, percentOfObjects. The input in left panel is common for both the tabs. So, in server.r i have seperate calculation for both "countsOfObjects" and "percentOfObjects". So, My plan is to have default view as "countsOfObjects" view with default select as "Count" in left panel and by selecting "Percent" option in left panel, only the percent view should be shown and the count view should disappear completely.

Comment: You can use @daattali shinyjs package. This is the link: (Hide/Show/Toggle tab)[https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/hide-tab]

Comment: Hi Valter... one doubt on the code toggle(condition = input$foo, selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=tab2]")

Comment: "li a[data-value=tab2]"  are css selectors used to identify the tab to show or hide. Open the app ie in Firefox and take a look at the source of the page with "View page source" and you will see all those html elements.